# Docker-compose says can't open file - no file on directory but the file exist

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

So this problem occurs when I have created a copy of a file and tried to run it. Say, I had a file name prod_run.py and I tried to make a copy and run it in dev_run.py. I made the necessary changes on docker-compose file for the dev server but when I try to run it, it says, can't open file, no such file or directory! So, I tried docker exec command to run the file from within the container to see whats wrong, but the problem still persist!

#### Expected behavior

The smooth building of docker container

#### Actual behavior

/usr/local/bin/python: can't open file 'dev_run.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

#### Additional Information

snippet of docker-compose-dev file

```
version: "3"
services:
  middleware:
    build:
      context: project_one/
    depends_on:
      - "redis_cache"
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis_cache
      - REDIS_PORT=5789
    volumes:
      - /home/$USER/.raster/:/app/_images/
    ports:
      - "8000"
    networks:
      - middleware
    restart: always
    command: ["python", "dev_run.py"]
```

Command to run:

```
sudo docker-compose -f "docker-compose-dev.yml" up --build --remove-orphans
```

Build information:

```
cache_manager_1          | [2020-04-07 07:40:25 +0000] [9] [INFO] Starting worker [9]
ban_manager_1            | [2020-04-07 07:40:25 +0000] [9] [INFO] Starting worker [9]
middleware_1  | [2020-04-07 07:40:25 +0000] [1] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://0.0.0.0:8000
middleware_1  | /usr/local/bin/python: can't open file 'dev_run_map.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Dockerfile of middleware

```
FROM python:3.6.9-buster

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
```

Project Structure:

```
parent_folder: 
   project_one\
     DockerFile
     dev_map_run.py
   docker_compose_dev.yml
```

Help is much needed :(

Comment: Could you please attach Dockerfile?

Comment: @EdwinClement added Dockerfile. It's pretty straight forward tho. Nothing is happening out there!

Comment: Also, it runs perfectly fine on my local machine ( a Mac!)

Comment: just noticed that its says `dev_run_map.py` is missing. That is weird, maybe you could try giving the entire path /app/dev_run.py. Furthermore, can you please tell if the file `dev_run.py` is in the current dir or project_one.

Comment: I have gave the project folder structure. @EdwinClement. It's in the current directory. I used docker exec command to get inside the container to check, sure enough it's there and it still could not run from within the container.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that, the best bet now would be to replace `CMD ls && pwd` and see what python sees

Comment: The filesystem inside the container is not the same as the filesystem on the host. You need to get the container to see the file by either mapping the file (or directory) into your container with the `volumes` entry or by rebuilding the container and copying the file into it from the build context.

Comment: The code snippets and error messages mention `dev_run.py`, `dev_run_map.py` and `dev_map_run.py`. Are you sure they are all named identical in your setup?